# Django: can't get new model to pass check

Tags: django, django-models

I added a new model, Posts. I consciously followed the way another model is set up. I never got this error about that older model, but maybe I will once this one is cleared. Anyway, whatever is wrong, I'm not seeing it. If you can point it out, that would be great.

**Portion of traceback from Heroku logs**

```
←[36m2015-03-19T11:16:05.134717+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m apps.populate(settings
.INSTALLED_APPS)
←[36m2015-03-19T11:16:05.134729+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     __import__(name)
←[36m2015-03-19T11:16:05.134731+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module     named posts.apps
←[36m2015-03-19T11:16:05.134831+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2015-03-19 11:16:05 +0000
] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
```

**posts.app.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'Baillee.apps.posts'
verbose_name = "Posts"
```

**posts.models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Posts(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

**posts.admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from Baillee.apps.posts.models import Posts

class PostsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("headline",)}

admin.site.register(Posts, PostsAdmin)
```

**INSTALLED APPS**

```
'Baillee.apps.posts.apps.PostsConfig',
```

I looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name
but like I said, I'm not seeing what's wrong. Thx.

Comment: In the question the file name is `posts/app.py`, is this correct? If so, it should be `apps.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is called:

`posts.app`

But you are referring to it as:

`posts.apps`

in your settings.py here:

*INSTALLED APPS*

```
'Baillee.apps.posts.apps.PostsConfig',
```